# Stack - Frame - Heap in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, heap-memory, stack-memory, stack-frame

All questions I found on this site refer only to `Stack` vs `Heap` and don't 
discuss `Frame` so here is my question. Don't get the difference between all three.

What I know:

`Frame`:
A `frame` is like a blackboard for instance variables of a function.
While the function is running all instance variables are stored
inside the `frame` of that function. When a function is called its
`frame` is created on top of the `stack`.

`Stack`:
A `stack` can be visualized as a physical `stack` of `frames`.
When a method (or function) is executed, it allocates a 
chunk of memory from the `stack`.

`Heap`:
All object pointers live on the `heap`.

Stack and Frame is clear (I think) but am I right with my `Heap` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Heap: All object pointers live on the heap.
>
> Stack and Frame is clear (I think) but am I right with my Heap statement?

Not quite. Most(*) dynamically allocated *objects* live on the heap, the *pointers* to those objects live in other objects (or variables, they are essentially the same thing) - which may be on the stack or heap. This distinction between "objects" and "pointers to objects" is important in Objective-C (it is not so in all languages), and its not correct to say all "object pointers live on the heap".

(*) "Most" as it is possible, and sometimes quite useful, to allocate dynamic objects on the stack. You cannot do this with Objective-C objects, but you can do this with C objects (and C is part of Objective-C). Don't concern yourself yet with this, this footnote serves more to illustrate that the model being described here is a simplification.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Heap is noncontinuous space for dynamic memory.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @CRD's answer...

Another way to think about the heap is as it's name implies - a messy pile.  We need the pointers to help find our way back to the objects that have been tossed on the heap.